# LongListSelector automatically at bottom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

So I'm getting a weird behavior with the native LongListSelector from WP8.

It's ItemSource is bound to an

```
ObservableCollection<Group<Something>>
```

Everything is displayed correctly, but when the list appears on screen, I'm at the bottom of the list instead of it's top.

The only thing I do is to fill the ObservableCollection via it's Add() Method.

Is this a known behavior or is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a normal behaviour as you are adding items one-by-one. for required behaviour kindly feed the list and then set it to observable collection

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution as it is indeed the fact that I added my items one by one that was causing this behavior. The solution is to Rely on the PropertyChanged event instead of CollectionChanged. At this point, using an ObservableCollection is not needed anymore. So I ended up using a simple List, assign the items and then calling NotifyPropertyChanged. Thanks for the help @techloverr